# Alfred workflow : SSH and Run Command upon successful connection

Tags: alfred

I want to SSH to a Remote machine and once connected in want to run a command navigating to one particular folder .

I have an alias for my SSH `friday` and once connected i want to navigate to a folder say cd cdd2/workspace and run a command run webapp

But when ever i try this alfred is not running the command in the same window and it falters. Also i want the terminal to be visible so that i can check for any unforeseen errors.

Currently i am trying using Aflred Terminal window but it do not wait for the ssh to be completed and runs its immediately even if i try like

`friday ; cd cdd2/workspace ; run workflow`

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at your example:

```
friday ; cd cdd2/workspace ; run workflow
```

Here you are running the commands on your local machine, after the ssh connection has exited regardless if it exits with errors:

This is because you've used the command seperator `;`.

What you want to do is to run the command on your remote machine, which you can do by specifying the commands you want to run after the ssh command:

```
ssh -p 12345 someuser@somemachine "cd cdd2/workspace && run workflow"
```

In this case we use double ampersand `&&` as command seperator, which will tell your (remote) shell to only run the second command if the first one exits successful without any error.

You might want to use `screen` to prevent your software from exiting if the ssh connection breaks:

```
ssh -p 12345 someuser@somemachine "cd cdd2/workspace && screen run workflow"
```

Now if the connection breaks, you can simply reconnect to your server with `ssh -p 12345 someuser@somemachine "screen -r"` to reattach to the running screen session, without loosing any data.

Comment: Seems like not to work 
 ssh url "cd cdd2/Users/rahsinwb/workplace/rahsinwb/ && bb run server" Connection Not getting established